Can you take the maximum result of a die roll when you are not pressed for time and there is no usage limit?
Can you take the maximum result of a die roll when you are not pressed for time and there is no usage limit?
As an example, the Artillerist Artificer subclass has a 'Protector' eldritch cannon whose description reads:

The cannon emits a burst of positive energy that grants itself and each creature of your choice within 10 feet of it a number of temporary hit points equal to 1d8 + your Intelligence modifier (minimum of +1).

When not in combat, if the artillerist in question has their eldritch turret deployed can they take 8 on the 1d8 roll in order to give everyone the maximum amount of temporary hitpoints as they can use this ability infinite times and could in theory just keep giving temporary hitpoints until they roll 8?

@Tarod This question is not specific to Artificers, that is just an example.

This is a question of table preference, not rules
The rule for temporary hit points in 2024 reads (p. 29, PHB):

If you have Temporary Hit Points and you receive more of them, you decide whether to keep the ones you have or to gain the new ones. For example, if a spell grants you 12 Temporary Hit Points when you already have 10, you can have 12 or 10, not 22.

This is pretty much as it used to be: you decide if you want to keep the new temp HP or the old ones. Activating your Eldritch Cannon is a Bonus Action. It says

On each of your turns, you can take a bonus action to cause the cannon to activate,...

That text is unchanged legacy from 2014, and now like then you can take actions and bonus actions outside of combat, even though you do not formally track the time in turns then. Otherwise, lots of actions like the Influence, Study or Search in social or exploration context would not be possible (p. 15, PHB). And all you need to take bonus actions outside combat is:

You can take a Bonus Action only when a special ability, a spell, or another feature of the game states that you can do something as a Bonus Action.

That is fulfilled here.
So the only question that remains is if your character knows how many temporary HP each casting created. If they don't then they wouldn't know when to stop to maximize the result.
Rules mechanics like turns, actions, hit points and Temporary Hit Points are directed at the players; they are constructs to resolve the game. The player characters wouldn't know about them, they are just acting and experiencing results.
However, the PHB is more about describing the rules mechanics, than about providing such meta-commentary, so don't expect to have explicit statements about this in there. For that we'll likely have to wait for the DMG, and even then we might not get it. The best we get in the PHB is stuff like the p. 15 inset "What Would Your Character Do?":

Ask yourself as you play, "What would my character do?" Playing a role involves some amount of getting into another person's head and understanding what motivates them, and how those motivations translate into actions. In D&D those actions unfold against the backdrop of a fantastic world full of situations we can only imagine. How does your character react to those situations?

So, in my opinion, this is more a question of table style than of strict rules: do you as a group, or does your DM, feel comfortable with such metagaming, or not?
For what it's worth, there is this very similar question for the 2014 rules: Is a character aware of how effective one casting is over another?, where the highest upvoted answer by our community was this one that likewise concluded it is a question of table preference. I do not think the situation has changed under the 2024 rules.

Might be worth mentioning that fifth edition, in both versions, has no rules equivalent to “taking 20”  (or even, really, “taking 10”) from third edition. It instead offers the DM advice to not bother with a roll at all in such scenarios, though I don’t think there’s any official guidance outside of ability checks.

If there is no consequence for failure and given enough time, I don't even have rolls for this as there is no point. The PC will eventually succeed, which is what the old Take 10/20 was supposed to convey. Now I might have the rogue roll to see if he rolls a 1 and breaks the lock so he has to find a different way to circumvent that door but other than that, he succeeds.
